# Can a creature split up movement more than once?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

Can movement be split up more than once, with different attacks and other actions in between?

### Background

I've have a 12th-level Half-Orc Monk character  with the **Mobile** feat, resulting in a movement speed of 60 (base speed of 30, +20 from Unarmored Movement, and +10 from Mobile). At this level the character has the Extra Attack ability, and (due to being at least level 6 in Way of Shadow) has the **Shadow Step** ability.

Here's where my question about the movement rules comes in.

In a room of multiple opponents, that is mostly lit but with sections of dim light that are just big enough for my character to use the Shadow Step ability, I want to be able to attack one target close to me, attack one target farther away, and then move back to safety. Since my character has low hp (due to a low Con score), quickly popping here and there to poke enemies with his spear and then moving to general safety would be nice.

I figure I could accomplish it like this, but it depends on whether I can split movement multiple times:

1. Start my turn by moving **10 feet** to my first target, whom I
   attack
2. Move **5 feet** to the nearest source of dim lighting (the creature wouldn't get an opportunity attack because of the Mobile feat, even if I didn't hit)
3. Use **Shadow Step** as my bonus action to teleport to a spot of dim lighting across the room (within 60 feet of course)
4. Move another **15 feet** to attack my second target
5. Move with my remaining **30 feet** of movement to a generally safe position.

**Is the aforementioned scenario possible since I stayed within the limits of 60 feet for my character, or would I only be able to split my movement into two different movements?**

It would be cool if I could split my turn into 4 movements, 2 attacks, and a teleport, but I feel like I'd only be able to do 2 movements, 2 attacks, and a teleport during my turn.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While the rules don't specifically state that you can break up your movement an unlimited number of times, that certainly seems to be the case.

> You can break up your movement on your turn, using
>   some of your speed before and after your action. For
>   example, if you have a speed of 30 feet, you can move
>   10 feet, take your action, and then move 20 feet.
>
> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon
>   attack, you can break up your movement even further by
>   moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter
>   who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature
>   and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make
>   an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

Since high-level fighters have up to 4 attacks with Extra Attack, this means that you can at least break up your movement into 5 sections. There's no reason why this would be a limit, however - it seems safe to assume that you can break up your movement as much as you please.

In any case, the only thing that it *isn't* specifically stated that you can break up your movement with is your bonus action. If your DM is an absolute stickler for "it doesn't say you can", then this is the point that you might not be able to win.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that unlimited movements between actions is possible.  The earliest I can Shadow Step is level 6, so I'm sure by then I'd have a pretty good feel of what my DM would allow and not allow during combat.

Answer (score 7):

### **Maybe**

The PHB reads:

> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action.

(Page 190)

It also reads:

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement **even further** by moving between those attacks.

(Page 190)

In the scenario you mentioned:

1. Move 10 feet before action
2. Attack (part of action)
3. Move 5 feet between attacks
4. You then make your bonus action.

There is a possible problem here: you are taking a bonus action before you have completed your action. Though I am not aware of any explicit rule stating that a bonus action cannot be taken during another action, your DM may not allow you to take your bonus action until you have completed your action. If this is your DM's decision, you could do the following:

1. Move before action
2. Attack (part of action)
3. Move between attacks
4. Attack again (part of same action)
5. Make bonus action
6. Move after action